# Use stored procedure with linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hi I use the following stored procedure,but i don't know how i use this with linq to sql..

I use the normal stored procedure with linq to sql, but this stored procedure retrives data on the basis of two tables,how can i do this please help me, thanks in advance

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.PackageTestForPerform

    (
    @Package_ID int,
    @Patient_ID nvarchar(50)
    )   
AS
select t.dep_name,t.test_name,t.sub_test_name,
CASE WHEN 
ISNULL((
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        from Patient_Package_Test p
        where patient_Id=@Patient_ID and p.test_code=t.test_code and p.Sub_Test_id=t.Sub_Test_code
),0)>0 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS [Status]
from packagetest t 
where package_ID=@Package_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

A class that holds the data.

```
public class PackageTestForPerform
{
    public string dep_name { get; set; }
    public string test_name { get; set; }
    public string sub_test_name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Then execute it like this:

```
var input = new List<object> { 1, "1" };
var ls= db.ExecuteQuery<PackageTestForPerform>("EXEC PackageTestForPerform {0}, {1}",
                                                    input.ToArray());
```